# Undecorated JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

I have create and internal frame which has been added to a frame but when I run it I find that the internal frame does not have any max,min,close,etc. I have not undecorated it and I have tried a couple of things like the look and feel and undecorated but nothing seems to fix it.

Here is my code (frame is the internal frame and outFrame is the JFrame):

```
 //Adding everything to contentPane.
    contentPane.add(label);
    contentPane.add(width);
    contentPane.add(textWidth);
    contentPane.add(height);
    contentPane.add(textHeight);
    contentPane.add(box);
    contentPane.add(bOpen);

    //Adding contentPane to the frame. 
    frame.add(contentPane);
    frame.setSize(500, 400);
    //frame.setClosable(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    //frame.setBorder(border);
    outFrame.add(frame);
    outFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: I think JInternalFrames are meant to be added to JDesktopPanes.

Comment: @schmop I agree with you.

Comment: Have a look at [How to Use Internal Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html)

Comment: use this constructor [JInternalFrame(String title,boolean resizable,boolean closable,boolean maximizable)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html#JInternalFrame%28java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "the internal frame does not have any max,min,close,etc."

Look at the [JInternalFrame API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html#setMaximizable-boolean-) and see [How to use Internal Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html).

You need to set the `iconifiable`, `maximizable`, and `closable` properties, as by default, they are set to false

- `public boolean setMaximizable(boolean b)`
- `public void setIconifiable(boolean b)`
- `public void setClosable(boolean b)`

Or construct the frame with those values

```
public JInternalFrame(String title,
                      boolean resizable,
                      boolean closable,
                      boolean maximizable,
                      boolean iconifiable)
```

Setting the values to true will give you your buttons to close, maximize, and iconify the frame

> "I have create and internal frame which has been added to a frame"

`JInternalFrames` are meant to used with and added to `JDesktopPanes` not the `JFrames`. See the link above I provided on how to use internal frames